# Tag is not closed

Tags: xml

In first line  of `AutocompleteTextView` I want to add namespace..but it gives me error like `tag name is not closed`...or tell how to add namespace here..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
           android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
           tools:context="com.nxtstepzedu.nxtstepz.nxtstepz.S1Activity"
           android:orientation="vertical">

        <schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".InstantAutoComplete
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/atcatogory"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:hint="Search for gym etc..."/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IN"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"/>

   <AutoCompleteTextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/atlocation"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
     android:hint="Search for locations..." />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to make AutoCompleteTextview custom but it tells me to add namespace and then custom class name. i did but it gives the error..like "Tag is not closed"..

Comment: First of all ensure you XML is properly validated the element <schemas.adndroid.com must be followed by a > or a space , it also doesn't have a matching number of quotes.

Comment: thanx for solution..this suggestion worked for me..

Comment: Cool, I've added it as a answer. Would you be able to mark it as the correct answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your XML is properly validated, the element  or a space and must have a matching number of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

i remove that class and kept AutocompleteTextView as it is and in OnCreate() , i used to methods...it's working fine....these methods..,

auto1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
                auto1.showDropDown();

        }
    });

    auto1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            auto1.showDropDown();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

in main class, auto1 is the object of AutoCompleteTextView